# Rails 3: Defining an ActiveRecord-less class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I define a Struct like this

```
 Struct.new("DefFgbs", :value, :condition, :school, :year)
```

I've been getting this warning:

```
warning: redefining constant Struct::DefFgbs
```

I want to define "DefFgbs" in one file, like one would do for a class, so I don't get the warning every time I need a "DefFgbs" object. How can I do this? Is there a better alternative to define an ActiveRecord-less model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define "DefFgbs" in one file, like one would do for a class,

So, do it. Put it in a file, and drop it in `app/models`. There is absolutely no requirement for your models to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
# app/models/def_fgbs.rb

attr_accessor :value, :condition, :school, :year

class DefFgbs
  def initialize(value, condition, school, year)
    @value, @condition, @school, @year = value, condition, school, year
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create the class in a file, as @meager suggests, and rather than put it in the `models` folder (which I like to save for models), put it in a folder in your of your liking under your Rails project, such as `app/classes/def_fgbs.rb` or `lib/classes/def_fgbs.rb`. Then, in your `config/application.rb` file, include the following:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/lib/classes"
```

or

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/app/classes"
```

It should pick it up from there.